# Gulp doesn't work and returns nothing, just opens the gulp.js file

Tags: node.js, gulp

I wanted to begin to use `Gulp` for the common simple tasks, like `SCSS` compiling. But once I run Gulp, it simply opens the file gulp.js.

After many searches and tries, I reduced all to the minimum possible: 
I uninstalled `NodeJS`, rebooted, and reinstalled it. Then I reinstalled `Gulp` globally. Then I created a folder test with inside a `index.html`, and a folder `scss` with inside my `style.scss`. I did `cd myfolder` in the console and installed `Gulp` inside (`npm init` then `npm install gulp --save-dev`). I also created the simplest `gulp.js` file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    console.log('Hello');
});
```

When I write "gulp" in the console, it does the same: it opens the gulp.js file without doing anything. It doesn't return any value either.

Does someone know about this behavior?

Thanks =)

Comment: I ran your code, and it works.. your filename is "gulp.js" or "gulpfile.js"? or, did you override the default gulp file name?

$ gulp
[17:47:26] Using gulpfile ~/gulpfile.js
[17:47:26] Starting 'default'...
Hello
[17:47:26] Finished 'default' after 154 μs

if you have access I would recommend John's Papa course [JavaScript Build Automation With Gulp.js](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/javascript-build-automation-gulpjs/table-of-contents), It's really awesome.

Comment: The file name is gulp.js

Comment: Try rename it to gulpfile.js ?

Comment: funny thing is that, when I run gulp with gulp.js and not gulpfile.js on my dir, I get the message: [17:45:23] No gulpfile found, so.. that's why I was asking if you override something.

Comment: Thanks guys... it is that. Renaming on gulpfile.js makes everything work! Now this is resolved, I need to know why, in every tutorial I saw on the Internet it is written gulp.js

Comment: great! @LightBen give some kudos to the guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please rename the file to gulpfile.js

(I deleted the answer because I wasn't sure about your filename)

By naming the task as default, it will run as you call "gulp" command.
For other names, you can call the tasks by name such as:

```
gulp check-style
```

for:

```
gulp.task('check-style', function(){
    // your code
}
```